# Bash conditional statement zero/nonzero unexpected results

Tags: bash, conditional-statements

In file.txt, I've got the following lines:

```
word1 blahbla
word2 blahbla
..........
```

Grep works as expected.

```
grep "word1.*word2" file.txt
```

gives me output, which I expect, because `word1` occurs before `word2`.

```
grep "word2.*word1" file.txt
```

gives no output, which I expect, because word 2 occurs after word1 and not before it.

The conditional statement does not work as expected.

```
[ -n '$(grep "word1.*word2" file.txt' ] && echo "output" || echo "no output"
```

gives me expected result, echoing "output", but ...

```
[ -n '$(grep "word2.*word1" file.txt' ] && echo "output" || echo "no output"
```

gives me UNEXPECTED result, echoing "output" when I'm expecting "no output".

What's wrong?

Comment: Command substitution doesn't happen inside single quotes.

Comment: You're just testing the literal strings, not executing `grep`.

Comment: You're also missing `)`.

Comment: Also, the default behavior of grep is to not match strings spanning multiple lines, so I wouldn't expect `grep "word1.*word2"` to match